# set font size in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to change font size using Jquery. I want to change font size of a div. I have defined default font size for body as 12. I tried to change it as follows, but it didn't work :(

```
$("#SelFontSize").change(function(){
$("#"+styleTarget).css({'font-size':'"+$(this).val()+"px'});    
});
```

Comment: a little bit more code + the corresponding html could help us help you. i.e. where does `styleTarget` come from.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#"+styleTarget).css({ 'font-size': $(this).val() });
```

By putting the value in quotes, it becomes a string, and `"+$(this).val()+"px` is definitely not close to a font value. There are a couple of ways of setting the style properties of an element:

**Using a map**:

```
$("#elem").css({
    fontSize: 20
});
```

**Using key and value parameters**:

All of these are valid.

```
$("#elem").css("fontSize", 20);
$("#elem").css("fontSize", "20px");
$("#elem").css("font-size", "20");
$("#elem").css("font-size", "20px");
```

You can replace `"fontSize"` with `"font-size"` but it will have to be quoted then.

Answer (score 3):

Not saying this is better, just another way:

```
$("#elem")[0].style.fontSize="20px";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#"+styleTarget).css('font-size', newFontSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try another way like that:

```
<div class="content">
        Australia
    </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(".content").css({
    background: "#d1d1d1",
    fontSize: "30px"
})
```

Now you can add more css property as you want.