# How to avoid use of body font-size property with jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, css, dialog

Hi I need to use jQuery dialog, but in all its examples it uses style `body {font-size:62.5%}`, I need to avoid this. This style affects an entire page. I've tried to style content in a dialog but it's not working.

Here is my [example](http://www.whitecastle.am/test/jquery/test/submit/submit.php).

Comment: Can you not remove that CSS styling? Seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Gary i try to do so, but its not working, you can check examples i posted below. I try lot of things and i still wonder why it is so complicated. I hope someone who had the same problem will be able to help me, but be sure thats not that easy as it seams :)
Please if you have time, check the links i provided under first answer you, can easily modify them by firebug...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that `body{font-size:62.5%}` css rule and add this one:

```
#your_dialog *{
  font-size:62.5%;
}
```

That will change the font only to your dialog. No js needed.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Edgar thanks for try, but it does not work.
Heres [example](http://www.whitecastle.am/test/jquery/test/submit/submit.php) i working on,
and [here you can see](http://www.whitecastle.am/test/jquery/test/submit/submit_1.php) what happens when i try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `#jquery-submit-form * { font-size: 62.5%; }` in your submit_1.php page in the `<style>` tag -- trying removing that and it will increase the font size. Also remove the same from the `<body>` tag. Your styling of submit.php looks fine for me in Firefox 4.

Comment: Gary thanks for answer, i removed both styles, but my problem is that i need to get same result like in submit.php without using body styling... Maybe i don't understand your solution, cud you explain?

Answer (score 0):

you can here find your answers:

[set font size in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236511/set-font-size-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Everything with a class of `ui-widget` gets a font size of `1.1em`. So don't give everything that class, or remove this rule from the css file.